# How to get the row and column number based on lookup dataset in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a question on filing value in one Pandas data frame based on the row and column number from another data frame, from example
Df1:

| ID | Cell |
| --- | --- |
| A | 97 |
| A | 98 |
| A | 99 |
| B | 10 |
| B | 11 |
| B | 12 |

Df2:

| Row | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 97 | 98 | 99 |
| 2 | 10 | 11 | 12 |

So using Df2, I want to update df1 as follows:-
Df1:

| ID | Cell | Row | Col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 97 | 1 | Col1 |
| A | 98 | 1 | Col2 |
| A | 99 | 1 | Col3 |
| B | 10 | 2 | Col1 |
| B | 11 | 2 | Col2 |
| B | 12 | 2 | Col |

What would be the best way to do this in Python to make it generic as the df1 and df2 are having many rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try `melt` then `merge`

```
out = df1.merge(df2.melt('Row'),left_on='Cell',right_on='value')
Out[159]: 
  ID  Cell  Row variable  value
0  A    97    1     Col1     97
1  A    98    1     Col2     98
2  A    99    1     Col3     99
3  B    10    2     Col1     10
4  B    11    2     Col2     11
5  B    12    2     Col3     12
```